# How to use WEKA with Xamarin for developing an android application?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, weka

As part of my project, i have been trying to use WEKA with xamarin for developing an android application for activity recognition. I know the possibility of doing the same in android studio using Java. But due to the constraints of the project, i'm allowed to use only C# for developing the application and i have been trying all the possible things to use the WEKA package with Xamarin, but none of them seem to be working.
1.I have tried creating a binding library for adding the JAR file -> resulted in too many errors (198 to be exact and 289 warnings)
2.I have tried converting the jar file to dll file using ikvm.net -> doesn't seem to be working either.

Much appreciated if somebody could provide some advices on how to make the WEKA package available in Xamarin.

Comment: http://www.jon-douglas.com/2016/10/28/porting-android-libraries-to-xamarin-android/ - Unfortunately your best bet is a Binding Project in which you'll have to resolve your binding errors.

https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb

Comment: Along with @JonDouglas comment, you will also need to create a version of WEKA that strips out the GUI/Visualization components as it is designed to be run on a Desktop, not a mobile device before you preform a `Xamarin.Android` binding on the `.jar` (There are some stripped versions floating around, try Github, but buyer beware ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the replies @JonDouglas and SushiHangover . Correcting those errors can be a Herculean task for sure.  And just to add,   i have been trying with the 'stripped' version of weka actually.